# How to prevent VSCode from exiting Python environment after running code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm diving into using VSCode on MacOS for Python coding as an alternative to PyCharm. When executing code, I run debug (F5) and it'll run my code, but once it's done running it exits the environment back to the integrated terminal. Is there a config/setting to stay in the Python environment so that I can keep executing Python inputs manually?

Comment: You found anything new?

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to select all (CMD+A/CTRL+A) and "Run Selection in Terminal" (Shift + Enter). This leaves the python environment open, it's not perfect but it works. Cursor is still in the code field, however, so if you try to enter a command while all your code is selected you'll delete it all which I did multiple times (thank you undo).

VSCode is, however, giving me lots of grief with recognizing indentation. It seems that the installation of pylint messed this up, I disabled it and it's still not recognizing correct indentation. Exceptions being thrown left and right.

Comment: As long as it works. At least I tried.

Comment: Opened a discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/discussions/16082

Answer (score 0):

The issue I created [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100021) might shed some light in this regard. See details below:

---

## Versions

### VSCode Version:

> Version: 1.46.0 (system setup)
>   Commit: a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321
>   Date: 2020-06-10T09:03:20.462Z
>   Electron: 7.3.1
>   Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
>   Node.js: 12.8.1
>   V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
>   OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041

---

### OS Version:

> Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19041 Build 19041

---

### Extensions installed

- DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint@0.36.0
- donjayamanne.githistory@0.6.5
- eamodio.gitlens@10.2.2
- ExodiusStudios.comment-anchors@1.7.1
- Gimly81.matlab@2.0.0
- GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github@0.16.1
- lextudio.restructuredtext@128.0.0
- ms-azuretools.vscode-docker@1.2.1
- ms-python.python@2020.5.86806
- ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl@0.44.2
- ms-vscode.powershell@2020.6.0
- vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons@10.1.1

---

## Steps to Reproduce:

1. Clone this [repo](https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/time_series_predictor/tree/ebd56ac3c43acbb04edabd69f1e9f38ca29d0481).
2. Place a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/time_series_predictor/blob/ebd56ac3c43acbb04edabd69f1e9f38ca29d0481/time_series_predictor/sklearn/compose/_target.py#L179).
3. F5, Debug Python File [run_this.py](https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/time_series_predictor/blob/ebd56ac3c43acbb04edabd69f1e9f38ca29d0481/run_this.py).

to check. -->
Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: Yes/No

### One probably can't debug without Python extension.

## Current result:

Once the breakpoint is reached, note that Variables, Locals to the top left of the screen displays a rolling animation as if it were trying to resolve local variables.

[image: Imgur]

After a while the debug is terminated abnormally.

---

Comment: Please include the link's content in your answer; this is helpful because the website that is linked may go down. It's a rule here. Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/500111), and read about [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Answer (score -2):

Try doing ctrl + F5 instead of only F5- this option starts the program without debugging it, as written [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

Comment: Same result, it just exits back to the terminal after running the code.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to execute the commands manually then you can start a REPL:

Press Ctrl+Shift+P and type - Python: Start REPL

It opens an interactive python shell with your current environment activated.

Comment: Is there any way to point the debugger to the REPL? Doing this doesn't allow any of my code to be passed through

Comment: You can open the directory where your code is present in VS Code and then Start the REPL. Then you can simply import your various functions and execute them.